# PostStarthook exited with 126

Tags: shell, kubernetes, hook, lifecycle

I need to copy some configuration files already present in a location B to a location A where I have mounted a persistent volume, in the same container.
for that I tried to configure a post start hook as follows

```
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command:
            - "sh"
            - "-c"
            - >
              if [! -d "/opt/A/data" ] ; then
                cp -rp /opt/B/. /opt/A;
              fi;
              rm -rf /opt/B
```

but it exited with 126
Any tips please

Comment: Can you use a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/), instead of trying to manage persistent volumes?

Answer (score 1):

You should give a space after the first bracket `[`. The following `Deployment` works:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command:
                - "sh"
                - "-c"
                - >
                  if [ ! -d "/suren" ] ; then
                    cp -rp /docker-entrypoint.sh /home/;
                  fi;
                  rm -rf /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

So, this nginx container starts with a `docker-entrypoint.sh` script by default. After the container has started, is won't find the directory **suren**, that will give `true` to the `if` statement, it will copy the script into `/home` directory and remove the script from the root.

```
# kubectl exec nginx-8d7cc6747-5nvwk 2> /dev/null -- ls /home/
docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Thanks @suren, but still exited with 126

Comment: can you paste your entire yaml?

Comment: please check next comment

Comment: ok. I reproduced your error, and now I get 126 error, but it is not due to the `postStart`, but some permissions in the container. `postStart` works just fine. What do you see with `kubectl logs POD_NAME`?

Comment: no idea then. To focus on the 126, it means that the file is there, but it is not executable. So, if you would do something like this `sh -c /home/some_file`, and this file is not executable, then you would get 126. That's from outside the container.

Comment: yes exactly. For that I ve created a configmap and put the script, gave it privileges but the issue persists.

Comment: https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/pod-lifecycle-container-lifecycle-hooks-and-restartpolicy_594727

Comment: when I added the sleep command as mentioned in the link at the container level, files copied and the exited 126 disappear but the pod remains running 0/1

Comment: you don't have a problem with the script. your problem is within the container. make a huge post, give all the information you have got; logs, pod descriptions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: oracledb
      labels:
        app: oracledb
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: oracledb
      strategy:
        type: Recreate
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: oracledb
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: DB_SID
              value: ORCLCDB
            - name: DB_PDB
              value: pdb
            - name: DB_PASSWD
              value:  pwd
            image: oracledb
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: oracledb
            lifecycle:
              postStart:
                exec:
                  command:
                    - "sh"
                    - "-c"
                    - >
                      if [ ! -d "/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB" ] ; then
                        cp -rp /opt/oracle/files/* /opt/oracle/oradata;
                      fi;
                      rm -rf /opt/oracle/files/
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/oracle/oradata
              name: oradata
          securityContext:
            fsGroup: 54321
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
          volumes:
          - name: oradata
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: oradata
```